# Python file delete PermissionError: [WinError 32]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, urllib, hashlib

I am trying to delete a duplicated image by comparing md5 file hash.

my code is

```
from PIL import Image
import hashlib
import os
import sys
import io


img_file = urllib.request.urlopen(img_url, timeout=30)
f = open('C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\ + img_name, 'wb')
f.write(img_file.read())
f.close   # subject image, status = ok

im = Image.open('C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\ + img_name)
m = hashlib.md5()                # get hash
with io.BytesIO() as memf:
    im.save(memf, 'PNG')
    data = memf.getvalue()
    m.update(data)
    md5hash = m.hexdigest()     # hash done, status = ok
im.close()

if md5hash in hash_list[name]:   # comparing hash
    os.remove('C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\ + img_name) # delete file, ERROR
else:
    hash_list[name].append(m.hexdigest())
```

and i get this error

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\myimage.jpg'
```

I tried admin command prompt, but still getting this error. Could you find what is accessing the file?

Comment: use two *single qoute* rather than one inside the parenthesis, like `open('C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\ + img_name', 'wb')` and `Image.open('C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\ + img_name')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just noticed you're using `f.close` instead of `f.close()`

Add () and check if problem still occurs.

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue has indeed been as Adrian Daniszewski said, however, there are quite few more programming problems with your code.

First of all, you should familiarize yourself with `with`. You use `with` for `BytesIO()` but it can also be used for opening files.
The benefit of `with open(...) as f:` is the fact that you don't have to search whether you closed the file or remember to close it. It will close the file at the end of its indentation.

Second, there is a bit of duplication in your code. Your code should be DRY to avoid being forced to change multiple locations with the same stuff.
Imagine having to change where you save the byte files. Right now you will be forced to change in three different locations.
Now imagine not noticing one of these locations.

My suggestion would be first of all to save the path to a variable and use that -
`bytesimgfile = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\' + img_name`

An example to use `with` in your code would be like this:

```
with open(bytesimgfile , 'wb') as f:
      f.write(img_file.read())
```

A full example with your given code:

```
from PIL import Image
import hashlib
import os
import sys
import io


img_file = urllib.request.urlopen(img_url, timeout=30)
bytesimgfile = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\' + img_name
with open(bytesimgfile , 'wb'):
    f.write(img_file.read())

with Image.open(bytesimgfile) as im:
    m = hashlib.md5()                # get hash
    with io.BytesIO() as memf:
        im.save(memf, 'PNG')
        data = memf.getvalue()
        m.update(data)
        md5hash = m.hexdigest()     # hash done, status = ok

if md5hash in hash_list[name]:   # comparing hash
    os.remove(bytesimgfile) # delete file, ERROR
else:
    hash_list[name].append(m.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Really appreciated.